# The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute sql statements

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, exception, transactionscope

I am getting this error

> The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute sql statements.

i have an Excel file that contains about 6000 rows and I uploaded these file into Data table in typed dataset, then I am trying to apply my business logic on these rows in dt.

The exception throws from the second loop and I have to do two loops; why does this exception occur, and how can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = SysInfo.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {

        //Here is my Typed dataset

        //Method Looping through row in Datatable & Calling DB

        //another Method Looping through row in Datatable & Calling DB

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
```

Comment: Without some code of your inner loops it is difficult to say what's wrong here. And please, don't catch exception and rethrow the same. It destroys precious informations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by adding the below lines in App.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.transactions>
        <defaultSettings timeout="00:01:30" />
    </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

and this in Machine.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.transactions>
        <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:01:30" />
    </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

As this process takes a very long time greater than 10 minutes, so I found that I need to overwrite this value with a higher one.

Comment: Path of Machine Config %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config